# Why is $localStorage not updated when using angular.merge

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage

I have an array of objects on my local storage. That I want to "synchronize" with the server when marked by "toSync=true".

So I `filter` my array to keep only `obj.toSync==true` and `forEach` I do an `$http.put` with a success callback that set `obj.toSync=false` and everything is fine and updated to `$localStorage`. Or **was** fine..

Because the server respond to the put with some other fields that may have changed, I changed the success callback to do `angular.merge(obj, rsp.data)` prior to `obj.toSync=false`.

But since I do `angular.merge` the `obj` is not updated on `$localStorage`. Of course I can explicitly store it again but I would like to understand why before passing `$localStorage` to a bunch of functions.

It is more or less like if the `angular.merge` is changing the *"reference"* to `obj`.

Answer (score 0):

`$localStorage` returns objects from the local storage, which is a database that you can find in every modern browser.

This database stores everything as a string. Those data won't change, unless you do it on purpose. You have no choice but updating the localStorage each time your object is updated.

Comment: God you're right deeper in the code there is a 'SetXyz(id, object)` that explicitly add/replace into `$localStorage`. That make me sad because actually all the "synchronization" is made by the object itself. Now I had to pass `$localStorage` as third parameter to the `sync` function (or move everything to a service and make the object anemic).   Thanks anyway

Comment: @Anonymous what does mean anemic? (non english speaker here).
btw,  I updated your title to fit better to the question/answer

Comment: @Jean-Philippe, By _anemic_ I mean they have no behavior at all, they only contains data (akka DTOs).